# How to dynamically create multiPolygons Arrays?

Tags: angular, typescript, geojson, turfjs

My goal is to build a `turf.js` multiPolygon.
This kind of hard-coding is working fine:

```
const searchWithin = turf.multiPolygon(
[
    [[
        [-0.607051, 44.840753], 
        [-0.543708, 44.832962], 
        [-0.52225, 44.820544], 
        [-0.566367, 44.808853], 
        [-0.586367, 44.788853], 
        [-0.607051, 44.840753]
    ]],
    [[
        [5.39014, 43.279295], 
        [5.393069, 43.279249], 
        [5.391814, 43.278421], 
        [5.390709, 43.278749], 
        [5.3909, 43.2785], 
        [5.39014, 43.279295]
    ]]
]);
```

As you can see, there is 3 levels of brackets before getting the coordinates arrays.
Coming from the database, I am getting:

```
[
    [
        [-0.607051, 44.840753], 
        [-0.543708, 44.832962], 
        [-0.52225, 44.820544], 
        [-0.566367, 44.808853], 
        [-0.586367, 44.788853], 
        [-0.607051, 44.840753]
    ],
    [
        [5.39014, 43.279295], 
        [5.393069, 43.279249], 
        [5.391814, 43.278421], 
        [5.390709, 43.278749], 
        [5.3909, 43.2785], 
        [5.39014, 43.279295]
    ]
]
```

To get data from the Database:

```
.subscribe((response) => {
      this.locations = response;
      this.polygonsArray.push(this.locations);
      this.locations.forEach(element => {          
this.polygons.push(element.geoDefinition.features['0'].geometry.coordinates);
```

with polygons declared as:

```
polygons: number[][][] = [];
```

I tried:

```
this.polygons.push('['+element.geoDefinition.features['0'].geometry.coordinates)+']';
```

but coordinates are numbers so I cannot concatenate.

How could I do to have this structure with 3 square-brackets, please? Any help would be very helpful.

I thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: It is not clear what you are going to embed in what. Could you please clarify expected structure with locations, polygons, polygonArray etc?

Comment: I want to have this.locations in the correct turf.multiPolygon format i.e. with [[ added before each polygon coordinates declaration and ]] added after each polygon coordinates declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear about expected structure. But first notable things are:

1. If polygons are 3 dimension array like `polygons: number[][][] = [];`, you can't push number directly to it, like `polygons.push(5)`, you have to take into account structure:

`polygons[0][0].push(5)` or `polygons.push([[5]])`;

2. Another thing is `this.polygonsArray.push(this.locations);` - it should be at least `this.polygonsArray.push(...this.locations);` as push would add entire `this.locations` array as first element of `this.polygonsArray`.
3. And the last. If you push something like `this.polygons.push('['+something+']');` - you just push a string to the simple array. Instead of that you can use

   `this.polygons[0].push(something);`

Hope it can provide some ideas how to organize 3-dimensional structure in your case.

Comment: Yes I think I still have to play with it. Thank you

Comment: I came accross your ideas. 1st/ this.polygons.push('['+something+']'); cannot work as something is Number format and must stay. 2nd/ `element.geoDefinition.features['0'].geometry.coordinates` is an Array of Arrays. In fact, I just need to add extra-brackets and I do not know how.

Comment: another comment: this.polygons is an Array of Arrays and turf.multiPolygon [https://www.npmjs.com/package/turf-multipolygon] is also an Array of Arrays

Comment: Use this.polygons.push([element.geoDefinition.features['0'].geometry.coordinates]); or this.polygons[0] = []; this.polygons[0].push(element.geoDefinition.features['0'].geometry.coordinates);

Comment: this.polygons.push('['+something+']') - is in your description, it should not be so. Instead I suggested this.polygons[0].push(something);